# Use .take() to index multidimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a multidimensional array of shape (n,x,y). For this example can use this array

```
A = array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
            [ 3,  4,  5],
            [ 6,  7,  8],
            [ 9, 10, 11]],

           [[12, 13, 14],
            [15, 16, 17],
            [18, 19, 20],
            [21, 22, 23]],

           [[24, 25, 26],
            [27, 28, 29],
            [30, 31, 32],
            [33, 34, 35]]])
```

I then have another multidimensional array that has index values that I want to use on the original array, A. This has shape (z,2) and the values represent row values index’s

```
Row_values = array([[0,1],
                    [0,2],
                    [1,2],
                    [1,3]])
```

So I want to use all the index values in row_values to apply to each of the three arrays in A so I end up with a final array of shape (12,2,3)

```
Result = ([[[0,1,2],
            [3,4,5]],
           [[0,1,2],
            [6,7,8]],
           [[3,4,5],
            [6,7,8]]
           [[3,4,5],
            [9,10,11],
           [[12,13,14],
            [15,16,17]],
           [[12,13,14],
            [18,19,20]],
           [[15,16,17],
            [18,19,20]],
           [[15,16,17],
            [21,22,23]],
           [[24,25,26],
            [27,28,29]],
           [[24,25,26],
            [30,31,32]],
           [[27,28,29],
            [30,31,32]],
           [[27,28,29],
            [33,34,35]]]
```

I have tried using np.take() but haven’t been able to make it work. Not sure if there’s another numpy function that is easier to use

Comment: What would be the expected output?

Comment: @Ch3steR added in what the final array would look like

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, now it's more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can advantage of [*NumPy*'s advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) and using [`np.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) and [`np.tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) along with it.

```
cidx = np.tile(Row_values, (A.shape[0], 1))
ridx = np.repeat(np.arange(A.shape[0]), Row_values.shape[0])

out = A[ridx[:, None], cidx]
# out.shape -> (12, 2, 3)
```

---

Using [`np.take`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take.html)

```
np.take(A, Row_values, axis=1).reshape((-1, 2, 3))
# Or
A[:, Row_values].reshape((-1, 2, 3))
```

Output:

```
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5]],

       [[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]],

       [[12, 13, 14],
        [18, 19, 20]],

       [[15, 16, 17],
        [18, 19, 20]],

       [[15, 16, 17],
        [21, 22, 23]],

       [[24, 25, 26],
        [27, 28, 29]],

       [[24, 25, 26],
        [30, 31, 32]],

       [[27, 28, 29],
        [30, 31, 32]],

       [[27, 28, 29],
        [33, 34, 35]]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution and the reading material, need to look into this more

Comment: @E.hendrix Added alternative using `np.take` too.